Large cardinals beyond choice and HOD(Ord^ω)
Are Reinhardt and Berkeley cardinals (and even a stationary class of club Berkeley cardinals) consistent with $V=\mathrm{HOD}(\mathrm{Ord}^ω)$ ?
It seems natural to expect no, but I do not see a proof.  I am fine with assuming dependent choice.
Negative results: Every set is generic over HOD, so Reinhardt (and Berkeley) cardinals contradict $∃X \; V=\mathrm{HOD}(X)$.  The reason is that using Kunen's inconsistency and its proof using disjoint stationary sets, for $V$ satisfying ZFC and $V⊆M⊆V[G]$ with $G$ $λ^+\text{-cc}$ generic over $V$ (this includes all small forcings) and transitive $M⊨\text{ZF}$, $V_{λ+2}^M$ cannot be nontrivially elementarily self-embeddable in $V[G]$. (Side note:  Furthermore, for $S$ encoding a partition of cofinality $ω$ ordinals $<λ^+$ into $λ^+$ disjoint stationary sets, there is no nontrivial elementary $j∈M:(V_{λ+1}^M,∈,S)→(V_{λ+1}^M,∈,T)$.  For $T$ we only get stationarity for definable (from parameters) clubs here, but $j∈M$ makes the ω-club of $j$ fixed points definable.)  See also Generalizations of the Kunen Inconsistency (Hamkins, Kirmayer, Perlmutter).
However, while under $V=\mathrm{HOD}(\mathrm{Ord}^ω)$ every set is $Δ^V_2$ definable from a countable sequence of ordinals, a sequence defining $j:V_{λ+2}→V_{λ+2}$ might be outside of $V_{λ+2}$.  Still, for sufficiently closed countable cofinality $λ$, assuming DC, every subset of $V_λ$ would be $Δ^{V_λ}_2$ in a countable subset of $λ$.
$\mathrm{HOD}(\mathrm{Ord}^ω)$ is notable as a natural choice for definable determinacy axioms.  Under $\text{ZF + DC + AD}_ℝ$, $V=\mathrm{HOD}(ℝ)$ is false, but every set of reals is definable from a countable sequence of ordinals below $Θ$ (and is thus in $\mathrm{HOD}(\mathrm{Ord}^ω)$ ).  On the other hand, the Chang model $L(\mathrm{Ord}^ω)$ has bounded complexity under large cardinal axioms, and one can reasonably expect that $V=\mathrm{HOD}(\mathrm{Ord}^ω)$ is also limited.
A positive result: Reinhardt cardinals in inner models (Gabriel Goldberg) proves that in NBG minus choice, a proper class of Reinhardt cardinals is relatively consistent with $V=L(P(P(\mathrm{Ord}))$.  Moreover, under a plausible assumption we can have $V=\mathrm{HOD}(P(\mathrm{Ord}))$:  His argument shows that under a Reinhardt cardinal, sufficiently closed ultrafilters on ordinals are well-orderable, which suggests that they can be ordinal definable.  In turn, an elementary $j:P(\mathrm{Ord})→P(\mathrm{Ord})$ can be encoded by an Ord-sequence of ultrafilters on ordinals.  The result extends to a number of other closure points in the hierarchy of large cardinal axioms beyond choice, making them relatively consistent with $V=L(P(P(\mathrm{Ord}))$ and likely $V=\mathrm{HOD}(P(\mathrm{Ord}))$.
